# Create list of hex codes from range

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of all hex codes from a known range. Examples of ranges are. 008000 to 00FFFF   400000 to 43FFFF    E40000 to E7FFFF.  I was hoping to create a list using either excel or python. As some of the hex codes will have leading zeros I would also need that format keeping. I was looking to save list as a text file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look into 'range' and generator expressions, you can try `['%06X' % idx for idx in range(0x8000, 0xffff)]`.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to python. But was told it would be the quickest way to create a list. Could you please show me an example of python code that can create a list saved to a text file.

Comment: Simplest way to write to file is ```open(<filename>, 'w').writelines(<list generated as metatoaster suggested>)```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
start_str = input('Start of range: ')
end_str = input('End of range: ')
filename = input('Output filename: ')

start = int(start_str, 16)
end = int(end_str, 16)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        f.write('{:06X}\n'.format(i))
```

## Output

```
Start of range: 008000
End of range: 0080FF
Output filename: out.txt
```

`out.txt` then contains the hex codes

---

As requested by the OP, here's a version that also appends a code to each output line:

```
start_str = input('Start of range: ')
end_str = input('End of range: ')
filename = input('Output filename: ')
ccode = input('Code name: ')

start = int(start_str, 16)
end = int(end_str, 16)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        f.write('{:06X}, {}\n'.format(i, ccode))
```

## Output

```
Start of range: 08
End of range: 0F
Output filename: out.txt
Code name: the CODE
```

## out.txt

```
000008, the CODE
000009, the CODE
00000A, the CODE
00000B, the CODE
00000C, the CODE
00000D, the CODE
00000E, the CODE
00000F, the CODE
```

Comment: I believe that you'll produce one less value than you expect.  In your example, your last generated number will be `0080FAE`...one short of the requested final range value.  I think you want `range(start, end+1)`

Comment: @Steve you are right, I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: thanks that works great , and yes the output is in the format 00800FF  one final question .is it possible to add some text to each code , I would like the text file to show the hexcode and then add a comma and then ccode , where ccode = is ccode = input('Code Name')

Comment: @JohnD I added to my answer a version which appends a code to each line

Comment: is it possible to have no space after the comma please , so it is the hex code comma ccode , with no spaces

Comment: Yes, just replace `'{:06X}, {}\n'` with `'{:06X},{}\n'`. Read up on [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for more options

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the `start` and `end` into integers, and use a list comprehension to make a list of hex strings.

```
def hex_range(start, end):
    # start and end are specified as strings, e.g. '0088FF' or '0x0088FF'
    return ['{:06X}'.format(i) for i in range(int(start, 16), int(end, 16))]
```

(Like @metatoaster's comment implies, `06X` in a format string means "width of 6 characters, pad empty space with zeroes instead of spaces, and do that in hex instead of decimal". [Here's the documentation on `str.format()`, if you need it](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting))

---

To then save that to a text file, you'd do something like this:

```
# assuming you've already read in start and end
hexes = hex_range(start, end)
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:  # open a file to write to
    outfile.writelines(hexes)  # write each element of hexes as a separate line in the file
```

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how you'd save the list to a textfile, one item per line. If you need more than that, I'd advise looking through a tutorial, or [python's documentation on file I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Be sure you're doing the right thing considering what you want the supplied 'end' value to your function to be.  If that value should be the last value produced, then you want `range(int(start), int(end) + 1)`

Comment: I tried the code replacing start with 00FFFF.and end with 400000 example def hex_range(00FFFF, 400000) but it comes up with invalid syntax error

Comment: I've fixed my solution - you want to use `int(start, 16)` and `int(end, 16)`, specifying that the numbers are supposed to be in base 16. If there's still an error, it might be because of how you're passing the numbers in. You either want to pass them as strings (`"00FFFF"`, `"400000"`; if you're reading from the console via `input()`, they would come like that already) or as properly-formatted hexidecimal numbers (e.g. `0x00FFFF`, `0x400000`). Just `00FFFF` won't work - python will interpret that as base 8 and `F` doesn't exist in base 8. Similarly, `400000` would be interpreted as base-10.